# How to get and save value from textbox that created programatically inside gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, postback

I have `gridview` that contains textbox that created in code behind

this is the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my page load is empty;
}
```

here is code for button after selecting dropdown and then click "Pilih" for showing gridview that contains textbox:

```
public void btnPilihKrit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtsubKrit = new DataTable();
    dtsubKrit = subkritMgr.getListSubKriteriaByIDKriteria(int.Parse(ddlKrit.SelectedValue));
    NbDtSubKritRow = dtsubKrit.Rows.Count;

    dtGvSubKrit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SUBKRITERIA", typeof(string)));
    foreach (DataRow row in dtsubKrit.Rows)
    {
        dtGvSubKrit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(row["SUBKRITERIA"].ToString(), typeof(string)));
    }
    DataRow dr = null;

    foreach (DataRow row in dtsubKrit.Rows)
    {
        dr = dtGvSubKrit.NewRow();
        dr["SUBKRITERIA"] = row["SUBKRITERIA"];
        dtGvSubKrit.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    gvKrit2.DataSource = dtGvSubKrit;
    gvKrit2.DataBind();

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtGvSubKrit;
}
```

this is code in rowdatabound for gridview:

```
protected void gvKrit2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= NbDtSubKritRow; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtNilai = new TextBox();
            txtNilai.ID = "txtNilai" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + i.ToString();
            if (i == e.Row.RowIndex + 1)
            {
                txtNilai.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                txtNilai.Text = "";
            }
            if (i <= e.Row.RowIndex + 1)
            {
                txtNilai.Enabled = false;
            }
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtNilai);
        }

    }

}
```

then this is code for getting value from textbox inside grid view:

```
protected void btnProsesPerbBerpsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvKrit2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox textBox = row.FindControl("txtNilai") as TextBox;
            string tb = textBox.Text;
            // do somthing with the text box textBox
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some illustration :

1. [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZh4L.png), after clicking button Pilih and choose dropdown, gridview with textbox will show up and I will fill the textbox with my own value
2. [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfvHG.png), to get value from gridview by clicking button "Proses Perbandingan Berpasangan"

anyone could help me?

i have tried many way like

```
TextBox box1 = (TextBox)(gvKrit2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtNilai")) as TextBox;
```

but textbox couldn't found from `findcontrol`. seems like `gridview` isn't created again on post back.

I have search some literature that I have to recreate `gridview` or make rowcreated event in `gridview` but Now I don't have any idea to do that.

Comment: why don't you use a `javascript` to collect the value ?

Comment: i'm not good at javascript but now i have solved my problem with different approach. i'm not using gridview anymore but just simply make table and then fill it with textbox. It didnt affected by postback. Terima Kasih Pak :)

Comment: Dulu sy pernah membuat hal serupa untuk membuat metode OMAX, persis seperti yg km bikin. By the way if you've solved your problem, please add it to the answer so anyone who have problem like yours can find it. :)

Comment: oh okay thank you Pak. saya sudah lama browsing2 stack overflow tapi baru sekarang sign up untuk keperluan tesis saya. dan saya tidak menyangka bahwa balasan atau komentar orang bisa secepat ini (dalam hitungan hari sudah mendapat saran atau balasan).

Answer (score 0):

As you created textbox on RowDataBound with ID like:

```
 txtNilai.ID = "txtNilai" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + i.ToString();
```

So you need to find with that ID :

```
string txtid = "txtNilai"+e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()+i.ToString(); // as per given inRowdataBound , so make sure to define i value.
TextBox textBox = row.FindControl(txtid) as TextBox;
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. forgot that I add index behind txtNilai

Comment: oh ya, i just remember that my problem maybe caused by control (textbox) that didnt created again bcoz of postback. but now i have solved my problem with different approach. i'm not using gridview anymore but just simply make table and then fill it with textbox. It didnt affected by postback.